# Python increase specific matrix elements

Tags: python, numpy

I want to identify certain elements in a matrix (which are say, smaller than 4) and increase the element by 1000. e.g. an element is 2, so this element is changed to 1002. How can I do this efficiently?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11]])
x[x <= 4] = x[x = x+1000]
```

The final `x` should be `np.array([[1002,1003,1004,5],[1003,1004,5,6],[1004,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11]])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11]])
x[x <= 4] += 1000
print x
```

Output:

```
[[1002 1003 1004    5]
 [1003 1004    5    6]
 [1004    5    6    7]
 [   8    9   10   11]]
```